# How exactly does Struts2 mapping work?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am new to Struts2 and would want to understand how exactly does it work? Basically how does it read from the URL, map it or forward the request, etc.

It would be great if you could provide a simple example as well.

Comment: [This tutorial](http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-tutorial/struts-2-framework-tutorial-1.html) explains your questions

Comment: Struts or Struts2 ? They are different frameworks

Comment: If you have specific questions please write them, otherwise, as others said, the Struts tutorial is the right place to start.

Comment: Related (for Struts2) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266748/at-a-high-level-how-does-struts2-work-im-coming-from-a-mvc-background

Comment: I am looking for Struts 2 and only wanted to understand it's xml config file..

Comment: Your question is too broad for a clear, concise answer. Try refining it to ask the specific question(s) you have about the XML. If you just want a general introduction, try looking over the documentation or tutorials on the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to explain it in a few lines but it is web programing so, basically, each jsp has an action and a form, struts-config.xml 'recieve' this information and the action is executed (if you have a form, it has to be valid). You are redirected to the next jsp at the end of the action and so on.

This is a extremly simple approach, you better follow the oficial doc :D

Comment: Actually I just need to understand struts-config.xml mapping and not Struts entirely...The official doc seems to be confusing and does not explain the same in an easy manner..

Comment: struts-config.xml is a Struts1 config file, struts.xml is the Struts2 config file.

Comment: struts.xml maps diferents actions, asociates a form to that action and tells the aplication where to go next (diferents views depending of the result: error, success, ...) after procesing the action.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way for you to learn the basics of Struts2 would be to have a look at the tutorials which cover exactly what you want: http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/getting-started.html